# Как сделать, чтобы при выводе сообщения пользователю не открывалось окно Tkinter? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, уведомления, сообщение

Всем привет! У меня такой вопрос: работаю с `tkinter`, а именно с библиотекой `messagebox`. Когда делаю функции `messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "ERROR")` или `messagebox.showinfo("Уведомление", "Вы успешно зарегистрированы в системе")`, открывается окно `Tk`. Я, конечно, сделал так, чтобы оно потом само закрывалось, но всё равно интерфейс с этим окном не очень...

***Если знаете как, помогите, пожалуйста***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто спрячьте основное окно, делов-то...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

messagebox.showinfo("Уведомление", "Вы успешно зарегистрированы в системе")
```